# tax section in magento backend disappeared under sales

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I'm missing the tax section under sales in my Magento backed menu . can any one let me know what possibly the reason is !!? i tried to go to permissions --> roles and made sure that i have all the admin permission available fro me as a user but still didn't work.refreshed the cache and didn't work as well .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi did you find out what causes this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect an module that you have installed is blocking the access to the tax section.
Try disabling all the none core modules and enable them one by one to figure out which one is responsible for not giving you access.

Also relogin in the admin every time (disable & refresh cache every time).

If its still missing when you have disabled all the modules, try a reinstall of the core files.